# Extracting really small details from high resolution pictures with CNN's

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I am trying to fine-tune a CNN model using Keras, to detect if a clothing item has any defects on it. These can be stains, holes, pet hair etc. My problem is that I am getting the input from the user, and usually the picture user uploads is really high resolution, and when it is resized before inference, the detail I want my model to extract is lost. So when I try my model with test data, it performs poorly.

- [For an example this is the original picture, a sweatshirt with stain, 1512x2016 pixels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8DOL.jpg)
- [And this is the stain I want my model to detect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpBkl.jpg)

I tried setting the input resolution to 900x1200, but when I try the GradCAM to see where activation map is active; I still see that the model does not pick up on the details I want it to. So my question is, how can I train a CNN model to pick up on really small details from high resolution pictures?

Comment: Why are you using a fixed input size? In general CNN can run on arbitrary sized images. The input size of the CNN does not have to be much larger, than the size of the defect you would like to detect. See for example https://learnopencv.com/fully-convolutional-image-classification-on-arbitrary-sized-image/ to learn more about this topic.